# How can I debug ASP.NET Core 3.1 using VS Code in Linux (Pop! OS 20.04 to add specificity)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

I'm having some trouble attempting to catch a breakpoint that I've set within my route on VS Code using ASP.NET.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Project>>> GetAllProjects()
{
    return Ok(await _projectRepo.GetAllProjects());
}
```

Even though I've set a breakpoint on the above, the moment I hit `/projects`which is my controller name, nothing happens. I've also tried `Console.WriteLine` but even that doesn't print out anything from my Debug Console.

My debugger runs, however, it's just that nothing is getting caught within the controllers.

My launch.json file:

```
{
   // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
   // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
   // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/DevsPlayground/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/DevsPlayground.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/DevsPlayground",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            // Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "^\\s*Now listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to Mono",
            "request": "attach",
            "type": "mono",
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 55555
        }
    ]
}
```

The only indications that I've gotten that the route was hit are:
 1. The view does show all the projects
 2. The last two "info"s on the Debug Console does show that I've invoked GetUserAllProjects

I'm also using the following Route attributes to call my controllers

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

```cs
// ProjectsController.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DevsPlayground.Interfaces;
using DevsPlayground.Models.Dtos;
using DevsPlayground.Models.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace DevsPlayground.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ProjectsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IProjectRepository _projectRepo;

        public ProjectsController(IProjectRepository projectRepo)
        {
            _projectRepo = projectRepo;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<Project>>> GetAllProjects()
        {
            return Ok(await _projectRepo.GetAllProjects());
        }

        [HttpGet("count")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<int>> GetAllProjectsCount()
        {
            return Ok(await _projectRepo.GetAllProjectsCount());
        }

        [HttpGet("{projectId}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Project>> GetProjectById(Guid projectId)
        {
            return Ok(await _projectRepo.GetProjectById(projectId));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Guid>> AddProject([FromBody] ProjectDto projectDto)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            return Ok(await _projectRepo.AddProject(projectDto, GetUserId()));
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Guid>> UpdateProject([FromBody] ProjectDto projectDto)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            return Ok(await _projectRepo.UpdateProject(projectDto));
        }

        [HttpDelete("{projectId}/delete")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Guid>> DeleteProject(Guid projectId)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            return Ok(await _projectRepo.DeleteProjectById(projectId));
        }


        protected Guid GetUserId()
        {
            return Guid.Parse(User.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
//Startup.cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
       name: "default",
       pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

[image]

Comment: What if you try `/Projects/GetAllProjects`? This is because your calling the `get` method on the `ProjectsController`, which not necessarily the `GetAllProjects` method

Comment: @MindSwipe Thanks for the input. I should've mentioned that I'm using the following Route Attribute:

`
[Route("api/[controller]")]
`
To declare these controllers

Comment: Can you add the part in your `Startup.cs` where you are defining your routing pattern? Because `/api/Projects` will call the `ProjectController.Index` by default ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#set-up-conventional-route))

Comment: @MindSwipe Sure thing

```csharp
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

I've also added it to the question above

Comment: Yes see, that's because the default action on every Controller is `Index`, not `GetAllProjects`. You need to specify which action to call at every API call. Switch you call from `/api/Projects` to `/api/Projects/GetAllProjects` to make a call to the correct controller and the correct action, then your breakpoint should get hit

Comment: @MindSwipe Thanks for your input. I was under the impression though that adding the route route attribute `[Route("api/[controller]")]` would allow my calls to `api/Projects` to be hit? ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#combining-attribute-routes)) Is that not always the case?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. But that is **not** the problem. The problem is that you're calling `/projects` and nothing is happening. That's because that request route doesn't point to anything. Please try to call `/api/Projects/GetAllProjects` instead and see if it works (which it should). The problem isn't your code or OS, but how your testing it